# Multi-label classification with nested features

Tags: neural-network, multilabel-classification

I need to perform a multi-label classification. I have three features and they are nested. I am unsure how to combine this or what kind of classification algorithm would be best. Some multi level neural network as shown [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-label-classification-with-deep-learning/) seems good, but the nested features don't seem to be taken into account there.

I present the nested features (X) and labels (Y) in the two datasets below: one subject ID can have one or more features and one or more classes. Features and classes can be 'occupied' by one or more subject.

Note: I have about 100k subjects, 1k features (at the third level) and 200 classes.

```
data_features
       subject_id   feature1   feature2   feature3
               1          a         aa          aaa
               2          a         aa          aab
               3          a         ab          aba
               1          a         ab          abb
               2          b         ba          baa
               3          b         ba          bac
               1          b         ba          bad
               2          b         ba          bad
               3          c         ca          caa
               4          c         ca          caa
               5          c         cb          cba
               6          c         cb          cbb
  


data_labels
       subject_id   label1   label2   label3   label4
               1        0        1        0        0
               2        0        1        1        1
               3        0        1        1        0
               4        1        1        0        1
               5        1        0        0        0
               6        0        1        1        1
               7        0        0        0        1
               8        1        1        1        1
               9        0        0        1        1
              10        1        0        1        0
              11        0        1        0        1
              12        1        0        0        1
```

I am quite unsure what algorithm would combine those the best? (I am skilled in R and SAS and decent in Python, but will learn any other language that would be needed)

Comment: Can you explain why the features are "nested"? What do they represent, and what is the relationship between a feature and a sub-feature? In other words, what would be the problem if all the features are "flatten", i.e. taking all the sub-features as if they are regular features?

Comment: If you know feature 3, you automatically know feature 2 and 1. If you know feature 2, you automatically know feature 1. That's what I mean by nested. 
Technically I could flatten and dichotomize everything, but it would give me a dataset with 100k rows and 2k columns. That's some heavy lifting neural network. I was hoping that, due to the nature of the feature data, some simplification existed.

Comment: "If you know feature 3, you automatically know feature 2 and 1" -> that would means that features 2 and 1 don't bring any additional information, unless there are cases where feature 3 is not provided but features 2 and 1 are?

Comment: Technically they aren't but they may have prediction use. A class may for example be linked to feature2='aa'. But if you ignore feature2 and consider only feature3, the link may get 'lost' in noise, because that specific class has multiple possible feature3 results, and 'aaa' and 'aab' would be considered just as different as 'aaa' and 'ccc'.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the relationship between a feature and its nested feature is from some kind of general information to more specific, right? Possibly something similar to feature 1 = brand , feature 2 = brand + model, feature 3 = brand + model + version ?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always a good idea to start simple, so I'd simply suggest to try with all the features, including the different levels of "nesting" so around 2k apparently. Given that the dataset is large, I don't see any obstacle to trying this way. For the same reason I would start with a very simple model like Decision Trees or SVM, which have the additional advantage that they're fast to train. This could be a first step which provides you with a decent baseline, at least.

If the number of features turns is an issue for a more advanced option, I think this is a good case for using [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) (for example PCA): this would reduce the number of features and also merge features which represent the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, looks like the nested features need not be nested and can be broken down into individual features.

E.g. if:

```
feature1 = brand
feature2 = brand + model
feature3 = brand + model + version
```

Then we should use the standard ML approach with features as:

```
feature1 = brand
feature2 = model
feature3 = version
```

The behavior of association among the features will still be captured by the ML model.